# GitLab and Jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I've read the differences between Gitlab Community and Enterprise in this page: https://about.gitlab.com/features/

Based on that page I understand the integration with Jenkins is only available in the enterprise version. However, I've seen that using web hooks I can trigger builds in Jenkins when a push happens in Gitlab.

So my question is which is the difference between community and enterprise regarding the integration with jenkins?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the merge request page, there is a state widget that shows the status of tests for that particular merge request, and on your project home page, there is test status badging. These two UI elements only show up if you enable a 'ci service' on the project. In community you can turn it on with Gitlab CI. In enterprise you can set it up to work with jenkins.

Comment: Ok, understood. And by the way, Git Hooks of Gitlab EE are like Git Custom Hooks of Gitlab CE are the same type of hook? The firsts are configured in the Gitlab application and the others are configured in the server's file system. Am I right?

Comment: @twk3 you wrote "In community you can turn it on with Gitlab CI. In enterprise you can set it up to work with jenkins". Do you mean that it is possible to get that going without enterprise through Gitlab CI?

Comment: GitLab CE only lets you configure the GitLab CI integration, and not Jenkins. There are jenkins plugins available to make Jenkins support being accessed through GitLab CI like requests. https://github.com/DABSquared/gitlab-plugin

Answer (score 9):

> Based on that page I understand the integration with Jenkins is only
>   available in the enterprise version.

This is no longer true, the [Jenkins GitLab Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitLab+Plugin) (from a 3rd party) works to hook Jenkins into GitLab as a CI provider.

The [wiki page has an example setup](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/wiki/Setup-Example) with lots of details you'll need to get it working.

This will give per-commit build/test status indicators in GitLab and also hook into the Merge Request system (both in the local repo and when merge requests come from forked repos).

Answer (score 1):

You can also integrate GitLab with Jenkins using the [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin).

An example of integrating with that plugin, to perform static code analysis on merge requests, is available in the [Violation Comments to GitLab Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violation+Comments+to+GitLab+Plugin) wiki page.